# Highpass filter like Photoshop

Tags: image, algorithm, graphics

Does anybody know algorithm similar to Photoshop High Pass filter?
I'm using [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter#Algorithmic_implementation). But it looks different and just "cut" low signal and i want to leave only high and low signals without middle.

I know that i should to use convolution, but actually i don't know how to do that properly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So do you want a high-pass or a band-stop filter? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band-stop_filter

Comment: Have you tried applying that filter using left->right then right->left directions to make it symmetric?

Comment: Definition of band-pass filter look like that. Variant with double passing isn't so good. Because I need absolutely uniform image.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just take mean value of sum of highpass and lowpass filters outputs. It will give You combination of low and high frequency in very easy way. Matlab-like pseudocode below:

```
img_low = low_pass(img)
img_hight = high_pass(img)
img_lo_hi = (img_low + img_high) / 2
```

Comment: Why do you average the low + hi image? `img_high` should oscillate around 0.

Comment: You're right but I'm using linear algorithm and effect looks like slided to right side and i want to get uniformly result